# How to filter a Flutter Future<List> with a SearchBar widget?

Tags: flutter, dart, web

I am making a WEB application and trying to filter the gameRooms list so when the user fill the SearchBar with some text it will be filtered to only show the rooms with the given name.

getGameRooms is a mock implementation of a future API call.

Below is my code:

```
import 'package:boardhub/entities/room.dart';
import 'package:boardhub/routes/dashboard/components/room_card.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Dashboard extends StatefulWidget {

  const Dashboard({super.key});

  @override
  State<Dashboard> createState() => _DashboardState();
}

class _DashboardState extends State<Dashboard> {
  Future<List<Room>>? gameRooms;

  Future<List<Room>> getGameRooms() async {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3));

    List<Room> rooms = List<Room>.generate(48, (index) => Room(gameName: "Sala de jogo $index", gameAddress: "Endereço $index", gameDate: DateTime.now()));

    return rooms;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    gameRooms = getGameRooms();
  }

  void filterRoom(String filterText){
    //TO-DO filter the room to be shown
    //Only show rooms which contains filterText in their name (inside Room.gameName)
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        const SearchBar(
          leading: Icon(Icons.search),
          hintText: "Dixit, Monopoly, Zombicide...",
          // onChanged: filterRoom,
        ),
        FutureBuilder(
          future: gameRooms, 
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
            }

            List<Room> gameRooms = snapshot.data ?? [];

            return Expanded(
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Wrap(
                  spacing: 10,
                  runSpacing: 10,
                  children: [
                    IconButton(onPressed: (){}, icon: const Icon(Icons.abc)),
                    for(Room room in gameRooms)
                      RoomCard(room: room)
                  ]
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I tried to implement a auxiliary variable allGameRooms so I wouldn't need to make another API call, but didn't achieved the expected result, since I still can't filter a Future, only List can be filtered (as far as I know).

Comment: you need to call your API on every search so that the results are not cached but always up-to-date?

Comment: @pskink no need for the data be always up-to-date. With the already fetched data I want to filter it through the search bar (no refetch is prefered but not mandatory)

Comment: check https://gist.github.com/pskink/c4d3615d93ba77ef16016aaca21e0f77#file-foo_search-dart-L64 the most important is `_getAPI` method at line 118

Comment: and if you want to avoid fetching your data multiple times use [AsyncCache](https://pub.dev/documentation/async/latest/async/AsyncCache-class.html) - in this case `debounce` is not needed at all since the filtering is done locally